# How do I get image and link on the same page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the link centered in the middle with the shopping cart image in the top right corner. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get them on the same line.

Here's an image of the problem (look at the top):

[image: Image of the problem]

Here's a code snippet of the code:

```css
.itemLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.cartImg {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline">
    <h1>
     <a class="itemLink" href="../index.html"><center>Island Time</center></a>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
     <img class="cartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/shopping-cart-icon.jpeg" alt="ShoppingCart">
  </div>
</div>
```

The link is the "Island Time" text at the top of the image and the image with the class `cartImg` is what holds the shopping cart.

If anyone can help me align the link and image at the top of the page with the link in the middle and the image on the far right corner, that'd be much appreciated. Thank you! Let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: _Please_ don't use `<center>` tags. That's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `<center>..</center>` and `float` for making layouts, these are outdated for a long time now. Use `display: flex` or `display: grid` when the first one doesn't cover your needs.

Your particular case:

```html
<div>
  <h1><a class = "itemLink" href="/">Island Time</a></h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt=''/>
</div>
```

```css
body{
  background: salmon;
}
div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2em 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div > img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/wvQdKeg

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I changed:

1. Removed the float from .cartImg class
2. Gave the container of the link and the cart image "flex" display and aligned the elements
3. Centralized the ".itemLink" with other adjustments

Note: You have to put the value of "translateX(50px)" half of the shopping cart width. For example: If the shopping cart width is 50px then change the value to "translateX(25px)".

Here is what you needed:

```css
.itemLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.cartImg{
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    /* float: right; */
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <div style="margin-left: auto; transform: translateX(50px);">
      <h1>
       <a class = "itemLink" href="../index.html"><center>Island Time</center></a>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: auto;">
       <img  class = "cartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/shopping-cart-icon.jpeg" alt="ShoppingCart">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first `div` is not centered with your solution =\ Here's an exmple: https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/KKrmdBo

Comment: Yes, I realized it after answering and then checking once again. Now it is corrected :) Thanks, anyways.

Comment: Sorry, but this fix is gonna work only when the image given is 100px width =).

Comment: Yes, in my solution it is a manual adjustment according to the image on the right. Always have to move the link right with the half of the image width value.